# Oracle : nested query in a select (compare dates)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I extract some data from a table, and one of the columns is a date. What I want to do is to add another column to the result that will be the result of a calculation made to that date :

```
select dateX, (select dateX - CURRENT_DATE from dual)
from TableX
```

The problem is how should I pass the `dateX` column to my nested selected ? I know the way I put it is wrong, since dateX doesn't exist in `dual` table.

Thank you

**EDIT #1**

Actually, here's my query :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
        id,site,TO_CHAR(dateX,'RRRR-MM-DD') startDate, (      
with test(d) as ( select TO_DATE(dateX, 'RRRR-MM-DD') from dual)
select case 
       when trunc(d) = trunc(sysdate) then 'PRESENT'
       when trunc(d) > trunc(sysdate) then 'FUTURE'
       when trunc(d) < trunc(sysdate) then 'PAST'
       end
from test
 ) startdateCompare
FROM 
        TableX 
WHERE 
        id = 6502
```

The `startdateCompare` is supposed to contain a value depending on the date `dateX`.

When I execute it, I get : `dateX : invalid identifier`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming dateX is of type DATE, you shouldn't need to call TO_DATE on it (in your inner query). You may even get the wrong answer. TO_DATE requires a character variable. You give it dateX, so Oracle will convert it to character using your NLS setting, which may not be 'RRRR-MM-DD' - and if it isn't, you may get an error when TO_DATE tries to convert that back to a date in 'RRRR-MM-DD' format.

Your query does not need a subquery. It should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   id, site, TO_CHAR(dateX, 'RRRR-MM-DD') startDate,
       case when trunc(dateX) = trunc(sysdate) then 'PRESENT'
            when trunc(dateX) > trunc(sysdate) then 'FUTURE'
            when trunc(dateX) < trunc(sysdate) then 'PAST'
       end  startdateCompare
FROM  (etc.)
```

Best,   mathguy

Comment: Definitely Math ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually *would* work.  The value of `dateX` would come from the outer query.

The simpler way to write it is:

```
select dateX, (dateX - CURRENT_DATE) as newcol
from TableX;
```

Comment: I have updated my question (cf. EDIT #1) with the complete query.